# Get Connection String from Web.config in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, connection-string

I want to know the ways to get connection string from web.config file in asp.net.

I just only know the below way .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

    namespace Sherserve.DataAccessLayer
    {
        public class DBGateway
        {
            public static string conString;

            public DBGateway()
            {
                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should be `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;` but that's about the only proper way you got.

Comment: so whats wrong with
conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ToString();

Comment: @Mitch please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76195/how-to-deal-with-have-you-tried-google-comments) - your comment is not really constructive to anyone.

Comment: @Ammar regarding your question - nothing utterly wrong, see my answer now I added some more information regarding this issue.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i have seen your answer... :) your answer increased my coding knowledge.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` is about the only proper way, to use it properly with sanity check you can have such code:

```
public DBGateway()
{
    ConnectionStringSettings mySetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"];
    if (mySetting == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySetting.ConnectionString))
        throw new Exception("Fatal error: missing connecting string in web.config file");
    conString = mySetting.ConnectionString;
}
```

This will throw useful error in case the connection string is missing, instead of cryptic "null object" error.

Worth to mention that the `ConnectionStringSettings` class is overriding the `ToString()` method:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.ConnectionString;
}
```

So it means that using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ToString()` is the same like `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString` however you still better perform sanity check and personally it looks cleaner to use the actual property and not depend on the class to give it.

Comment: where `conString` came from in the line `conString = mySetting.ConnectionString;` ??

Comment: @sam static field of the class: `public static string conString;`, see code in the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard in my case the code returns null always and I have connection string in my web.config as well.

Comment: @AkashPreet either you're using wrong name of the connection string, or the web.config you see isn't the web.config that actually gets loaded, e.g. several different web.config files. Otherwise there's really no way to get null.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the whole solution:-

```
string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
try
 {
   SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
   SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
   con.Open();
   dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "table");
   return ds;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
    }
```

This is how you can fetch records from database into datatable.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: i only want ways to get connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 string ConString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count -1].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a method on my WebAssistant Class.
i have a key on appSettings that contain my WebAppName, check the below line:

```
<add key="DOMAIN_NAME" value="mRizvandi.com"/>
```

and my connection name alwyas has "DomainName"+"DBConnectionString" template such as:

```
<add name="mRizvandiDBConnectionString" connectionString=...
```

Ok, everything are ready to get connectionstring without pass any string.

```
    public static string GetDBConnectionString()
    {
        string retValue = "";
        string domainUrl = "";
        string connectionKey = "";
        string dbConnectionString = "";

        domainUrl = GetDomainUrl();
        connectionKey = domainUrl.Substring(0, domainUrl.IndexOf(".")) + "DBConnectionString";
        dbConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionKey].ToString();
        retValue = dbConnectionString;

        return retValue;
    }
```

I hope would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me.
I've added the exception in case connectionString not founded in web.config

web.config:

```
 <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myaddress;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;User ID=myuser;Password=pass;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In my connection class:

```
static internal string GetSqlConnectionString(){

try {
    ConnectionStringSettings mySetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DataBaseConnection");
    if (mySetting == null)
        throw new Exception("Database connection settings have not been set in Web.config file");

    return mySetting.ConnectionString;

} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw;
}}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).